# How to handle the button click in Selenium Webdrive?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to `WebDriver`,and currently trying to write the code to click the button. The locator is not available so I have used *Xpath*,but it is not working as it should be. Kindly help me on this.

Button tag:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

My web drive code:

```
drive_url.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/button")).click();
```

Comment: Button Tag:<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your xpath in browser console. You can check xpath by writing `$x("<your xpath>")` in console. Try using `"//button"` instead  of what you're using now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be little careful writng the selector as well. Try to avoid flaky selector and make is as unique as possible.

```
By xpath = By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Try it')]");
drive_url.findElement(xpath ).click();
```

The above selector finds the *button* tag explicitly using **text** based search.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.tagName("button"));
String btnText= driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).getText();
if(btnText.equals("Try it")){
  btn.click;
}
```